# Azure B2C Rest API in User Journey body is empty

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a REST API call that I can call just fine using a validation technical profile, but if I add it to a user journey as an orchestration step, the body of the call is null when it gets to the backend API, thus erring.  I have following all the Microsoft Documentation and everything appears to be setup correctly.  The calls are in different IEF policies, but they all have the exact same REST Technical Profile.

Here is the technical profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="RESTTransactionalEmail">
      <DisplayName>REST API to Update the backend </DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://{Settings:APIURI}/apiendpoint</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="<key>" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="<secret>" /> 
      </CryptographicKeys>      
     <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_{Settings:ExtensionAppId}_memberid" PartnerClaimType="memberId"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="toRecipient"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="templateName" PartnerClaimType="templateName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="key" PartnerClaimType="modelKey1" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="phoneChange" PartnerClaimType="modelValue1" />
     </InputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

This is the orchestration step:

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="11" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTSendEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="RESTTransactionalEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Has anyone else run into this or have any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Could you add some of the XML from the custom policy?

Comment: Add the REST API technical profile and Orchestration step to your post. Also the input claims to the REST API will need to have been output via a previous technical profile. If the claims are output by validation technical profiles in previous orchestration steps, they must also be output by the parent technical profile to be available in any subsequent orchestration steps.

Comment: I edited the original post to add the technical profile and orchestration steps.  The claims are output as outputclaimtransformations and other claims in a previous orchestration step.

Comment: @user13129681 this looks good. Maybe it's your API that's not deserializing the body properly. Can you share your full policies xml and/or api code or details? Have seen this happening in .NET Core (No ApiController attribute), etc.

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla This is the same API that I can call from a ValidationTechinicalProfile without an error.  I'm only having an issue if it's called from an Orchestration Step.  I didn't think there was a difference, but is there a difference in how B2C calls the APIs in a ValidationTechnicalProfile or an Orchestration Step?

Comment: Can you post the technical profile that also calls the rest API as a validation step?

Comment: We got this working.  I ended up moving the REST API call to the extensions policy and then it seemed to work.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't work in the signin policy.